Calculating circle offset for each angle when reference point is not circle center
I try to calculate offset change at outer rim of a circle for each angle with respect to C1 but can not figure out. its is easy on the paper with geometry but very difficult to formulate it.
The origin for calculation is $C_1=(0,0)$, while the circle with radius $r$ is centred at $C_2=(h, k)$, which is $r_0$ from $C_1$, where $r_0^2 = h^2 + k^2$
We are given rays from $C_1$ at angles $\theta_i$ to the $x$-axis (between $0$ to $360$ degrees in $1$ degree increments), which define points on $C_2$ called $D_i$. Angle $\theta_i$ are $\theta_i\in \{0,1,\dots,360\}$.
Let $L_i = |\overline{C_1D_i}|$ be the distance from $C_1$ to $D_i$.
Offset $O_i$ is change of distance between C1 & C2 at each angle.
Problem: find $L_i$, $D_i$ and offset $O_i$.
After geometric study, I came conclusion that offset is only in relation with horizontal and vertical offset of circle center C2 (h, k).
When h and k calculated for each angle ($h_i$, $k_i$) and substracted from initial values of "0" degree ($h_0$, $k_0$), offset can be calculated. However, this is not the length L.
I found easily how to calculate offset for each 90 degree quadrant geometrically as below.
Lets say, horizontal offset of C2 circle to x-axis is h= +20, and vertical offset to y-axis is k= +40 and circle radius is r= 76.2.
Since we are turning around the circle, offset value sign will change every 90 degree quadrant in cartesian coordinates.
Horizontal and vertical offset (h, k) at each 90 degree quadrant will be;
at $D_0$,  (+20, 0)
at $D$90,  (0, 40)
at $D$180,  (-20, 0)
at $D$270,  (0, -40)
Also, starting value is zero at point $D_0$, therefore, the initial horizontal offset (+20) will be calculated double at 180 degree (+40) as its zeroed at $D_0$ .
Calculation of Offset $O_i$ for each quadrant will be;
Offset $O_0$ at "0" degree = 20 - 20 = 0 (set 0)
Offset $O90$ at 90 Degree = 20 - (40) = - 20
Offset $O180$ at 180 Degree = 20 - (-20) = 40
Offset $O270$ at 270 Degree = 20 - (-40) = 60
Since this is a perfect circle, offset must be equal at both x-x' = y-y' axis ($O_0$ + $O180$ = $O90$ + $O270$, e.g. 0 + 40 = -20 + 60, same rule also valid other angles 90 degree quadrant apart each other)
I tried to calculate offset for each angle,
Offset $O_i$ = ($k_0$ * Sin($\theta_0$) + $h_0$ * Cos($\theta_0$)) - ($k_i$ * Sin($\theta_i$) + $h_i$ * Cos($\theta_i$))
where,
$h_0$= initial horizontal offset at $D_0$
$k_0$= initial vertical offset at $D_0$
but I could not find a way to verify if it works.
and my trigonometry skill now too rusty for how to calculate $L_i$
and $D_i$($x_i$, $y_i$) coordinates of each point on the circle.


Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Is $h$, $k$ small compared to the circle's radius? If yes then the radial distance can be approximated into $r(\theta) = R + h \cos \theta + k \sin \theta$ where you can find the values of $(h,k,R)$ using some curve fitting algebra.

hi, (h, k) can be any value less than circle radius r

I am confused by the definition of the offset. Isn't $r_0$ fixed?

Benjamin, its confusing but ri is changes with angle as its represent distance between C1 and C2. Anyway, I removed ro, ri and put only description of offset. Offset Oi is change of distance between C1 & C2 at each angle

So you have a situation like this

Where there is an offset circle (green) of which you measure the radial distance $r_i$ from the origin and azimuth angle $\psi_i$ and you are trying to find the unknown origin center $(g_x,g_y)$ as well as the circle radius $R$.
The exact relationships to be used here are
$$ r_i = \sqrt{ \left( g_x + R \cos \theta_i \right)^2 + \left( g_y + R \sin \theta_i \right)^2 } $$
and
$$ \tan \psi_i = \frac{\left( g_y + R \sin \theta_i \right)}{\left( g_x + R \cos \theta_i \right)} $$
This problem is easily reduced to a curve-fitting exercise if you assume the offset is small compared to the radius.
$$ \text{assume:} \\ {g_x} \ll R \\ {g_y} \ll R$$
Then you can find using a Taylor series approximation that
$$ r_i \approx R + g_x \cos \theta_i + g_y \sin \theta_i + \left\{ \frac{-g_x g_y \sin 2 \theta_i}{2 R} + \mathcal{O}(g_x^2,\,g_y^2) \right\} $$
$$ \tan \psi_i \approx \tan \theta_i + \left\{ \tfrac{g_y}{R \cos \theta_i} - \tfrac{g_x \tan \theta_i}{R \cos \theta_i} + \mathcal{O}(g_x^2,\,g_y^2) \right\}$$
So by using $\tan \psi_i = \tan \theta_i $ and $$ r_i \approx R + g_x (\cos \psi_i) + g_y (\sin \psi_i)  $$
you do a linear curve fit from $N$ points that are measured for the unknown coefficients
$$X = \begin{Bmatrix} R \\ g_x \\ g_y \end{Bmatrix}$$
with the Vandermode matrix
$$ {\rm A} = \begin{Bmatrix}
 1 & \cos \psi_1 & \sin \psi_1 \\ 
 1 & \cos \psi_2 & \sin \psi_2 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & \cos \psi_i & \sin \psi_i \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & \cos \psi_N & \sin \psi_N \\ \end{Bmatrix}$$
and value vector
$$ B = \begin{Bmatrix}
 r_1 \\ r_2 \\ \vdots \\ r_i \\ \vdots \\ r_N 
\end{Bmatrix} $$
Which forms the curve-fitting problem with the linear system
$$ B = {\rm A} X $$
and its solution using the left pseudo-inverse
$$ X = ( {\rm A}^\intercal {\rm A})^{-1} {\rm A}^\intercal B $$

I did not read all your text because it was hard to read it. Based on your picture, I'll assume the following:

You have a circle $C$ centred $(h,k)$, radius $r$. So $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$.
You draw a line $L$ from $O$ with angle $\theta$. So $y=(\tan\theta)x$
You want to find the coordinates of the intersection(s) of $C$ and $L$.

It's probably easiest to solve the simultaneous equations above.
I attempted to clarify your question but was unable to understand what you mean by offset.
To be precise, I would solve the simultaneous equation as follows:
$$(x-h)^2 + ((\tan\theta)x-k)^2=r^2$$
This is a quadratic equation in $x$ which may give the $x$-coordinate of the up to two possible intersections of $C$ and $L$. From that you can figure out $y$ and the distance to the intersection from the origin.

Thank you very much for your comments. I simplified my query for more understandable. (x−x1)2+(y−y1)2=r2 is valid to find coordinates on circle for each angle when reference to circle center C2. However, reference is C1 in my query and this equation does not work. Also, y=(tanθ)x works to find Lo at every angle but not L1, L2...

I think the equation works (my origin is your $C_1$). Also, you can plug in the $\theta$ for each specific $L$.
